# What rows are included in Polars rolling calculations when `window_size` is "2d" or `timedelta(days=2)`

Tags: dataframe, datetime, calculated-columns, python-polars, date-arithmetic

When using `rolling_mean()` to calculate the mean of a DataFrame column, you can set the window by either specifying `"2d" | "2i" | timedelta(days=2)`.

If you have a DataFrame that consists of financial time series data, there are dates that are missing (holidays/weekends), there is not a clear depiction of how each variation of `window` will change the calculation window.

If the `window_size = "2d"` and there is a a missing date between two dates, the `mean()` calculation will only include 1 day in the mean calculation, and will not include the other day (that is not present). This should be able to be replaced with the last observation that the time series has.  Furthermore, if there is one observation in the new month, and the  `window_size = "1m"` then the calculation will just use the first value of the month in the calc, and won't include the lookback period of one month. A `timedelta(days=2)` argument, does not equal the same values as a `"2i` window size.

#### TL;DR

It is not clear what data is included during the calculation when  `window_size = timedelta(days=2)` vs  `window_size = "2d"`. What is thedifference between the two, and what is the best logic to compute a rolling_mean() of close prices with a "1m" window?

If the last date is Mar 1st 2024, I would want the calculation to include data from Feb 1st 2024.

I have tried a few testing methods to see the difference and what logic i expect to occur.

#### Dataframe

```py
df = pl.read_csv(b"""
date,open,high,low,close,volume,symbol
2023-01-03T00:00:00.000000000,129.39,130.01,123.32,124.22,112117500,AAPL
2023-01-04T00:00:00.000000000,126.02,127.78,124.23,125.5,89113600,AAPL
2023-01-05T00:00:00.000000000,126.26,126.9,123.91,124.17,80962700,AAPL
2023-01-06T00:00:00.000000000,125.15,129.4,124.04,128.74,87754700,AAPL
2023-01-09T00:00:00.000000000,129.58,132.5,129.0,129.26,70790800,AAPL
2023-01-10T00:00:00.000000000,129.37,130.36,127.25,129.84,63896200,AAPL
2023-01-11T00:00:00.000000000,130.35,132.6,129.57,132.58,69458900,AAPL
2023-01-12T00:00:00.000000000,132.97,133.34,130.54,132.5,71379600,AAPL
2023-01-13T00:00:00.000000000,131.13,134.0,130.76,133.84,57809700,AAPL
2023-01-17T00:00:00.000000000,133.91,136.35,133.21,135.01,63646600,AAPL
2023-01-18T00:00:00.000000000,135.89,137.66,134.11,134.29,69672800,AAPL
2023-01-19T00:00:00.000000000,133.16,135.32,132.86,134.35,58280400,AAPL
2023-01-20T00:00:00.000000000,134.36,137.08,133.3,136.93,80223600,AAPL
2023-01-23T00:00:00.000000000,137.18,142.34,136.96,140.15,81760300,AAPL
2023-01-24T00:00:00.000000000,139.35,142.18,139.34,141.56,66435100,AAPL
2023-01-25T00:00:00.000000000,139.93,141.46,137.86,140.89,65799300,AAPL
2023-01-26T00:00:00.000000000,142.19,143.27,140.93,142.98,54105100,AAPL
2023-01-27T00:00:00.000000000,142.18,146.23,142.1,144.93,70555800,AAPL
2023-01-30T00:00:00.000000000,143.97,144.56,141.87,142.02,64015300,AAPL
2023-01-31T00:00:00.000000000,141.73,143.35,141.31,143.31,65874500,AAPL
2023-02-01T00:00:00.000000000,142.99,145.61,140.36,144.44,77663600,AAPL
2023-02-02T00:00:00.000000000,147.88,150.15,147.16,149.79,118339000,AAPL
2023-02-03T00:00:00.000000000,147.02,156.31,146.82,153.45,154357300,AAPL
2023-02-06T00:00:00.000000000,151.53,152.05,149.75,150.69,69858300,AAPL
2023-02-07T00:00:00.000000000,149.61,154.17,149.61,153.59,83322600,AAPL
""".strip(), try_parse_dates=True)
```

```py
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from openbb import obb


_column_name_returns: str = "close"


def annual_vol(data: pl.Series) -> pl.Series:
    return data.mean()


data = obb.equity.price.historical(
    "AAPL", start_date="2023-01-01", end_date="2021-02-07", provider="yfinance"
)
data = data.to_polars()

test = data.set_sorted("date").select(
    pl.col(_column_name_returns).rolling_map(
        annual_vol, window_size=21, min_periods=1
    )
)
test2 = (
    data.set_sorted("date")
    .rolling(index_column="date", period="21i")
    .agg(pl.col("close").map_elements(annual_vol))
)

test3 = data.set_sorted("date").with_columns(
    pl.col(_column_name_returns)
    .rolling_mean(window_size=dt.timedelta(days=31), by="date", min_periods=1, center=False, closed = "left")
    .alias("vol")
)
```

### Goal:

if you have data that looks like this:
[image: Stock Data]
and the latest date is `2023-02-07`, then a "1m" rolling statistic would calculate from `2023-01-07`, or `2023-01-06` in the case of there being no data.

Comment: `"2i"` means “every 2-row window”, which it sounds like you want?

Comment: yes, that is close, but that keeps a fixed window. I would like the window to change size based on the dates associated.

i.e If there is a full year of data, a 'monthly' rolling statistic would be slightly different for each month, this anges from 19-23 days per month.

Comment: You seem to have a specific question about a close price 1m window: *"If the last date is Mar 1st, I would want the calculation to include data from Feb 1st 2024"*. Maybe you could show an actual example of what Polars currently does in this case and how it's failing?

Comment: Okay. That iw what I was trying to show with the `test` object. It shows that the calculations, while all expecting to have a `"1m"` rolling statistic and they should be equal, the values produced are all different, indicating a different calculation window for each.

21 rows, should be equal to `timedelta(days=31)`, as they both represent 1m worth of financial data.

Comment: @jqurious added an example and clearer explanation with picture.

Comment: Your code example requires installing `openbb` and `def log_returns` is missing so it doesn't run. This made it hard to understand the problem. You could serialize the frame e.g. `data.write_csv()` and inline it into the code to make it easier to run.

Comment: So for `test2` I think this is a bug in Polars. `.rolling(index_column="date", period="21i")` doesn't actually do anything because the index column is a date. The index column would need to be an "integer" e.g. `index_column=pl.int_range(pl.len())` - Polars should raise an error here I think.

Comment: okay, yeah that might not work, you may get a better idea if you take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78067709/how-to-calculate-a-rolling-statistic-in-polars-looking-back-from-the-end-date)

Comment: I edited in an example of what I meant by inlining the data. Your code contains `log_returns(data, _column_name="close")` though, so the example would still need some more fixing.

Comment: Okay, i fixed it up now

Comment: `data.to_polars().write_csv()` gave me the 39 rows I edited in but your images contain 50 rows so there is a mismatch. Maybe you can update with the data from the images. Using a 31d window on the 39 rows frame, 11 of them end up with a length of 22 so it's a bit unclear as to why they should be equal to the `21i` example?

Comment: @jqurious the 50 rows are just because I had another symbol in the data frame, doubling the size, I will update the data

Comment: Yeah, but even row 1 in the image is from `AAPL, 2023-01-03` but openbb gives me `AAPL, 2023-01-04` as the first row.

Comment: Hmmm, its giving me `AAPL, 2023-01-03` when i start at `2023-01-01`...just updated the data

Comment: If we take the date `2023-02-03` (index 22) with a `31d` window, that gives us a result starting from `2023-01-04` (index 1) which is `22i` rows. Am I misunderstanding something here perhaps?