# How to calculate a rolling statistic in Polars, looking back from the `end_date`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-polars, date-arithmetic, rolling-computation

I would like to calculate a rolling `"1m"` statistic on a financial data time series. Given that there won't always be an equal number of rows, per month calculation, unless you have exactly enough data to divide into months, which is uncommon.

I am trying to assign a column `window_index` to keep track of the rows that are included in the calculation, as i will use `.rolling().over()` expression to calc the stat on each window. I would like the `window_index` integer to be added starting from the latest date, and working its way back.

Here is an image to help explain:
[image: Stock Data]

Currently, what I am trying to do is add the `window_index` in groups denoted by the red and blue pen. Although I would like the data to be grouped by the yellow pen marking. The dataset ends at `2023-02-07` and one month prior would be `2023-01-07`, or the closest value `2023-01-06`.

This is the code I am using to achieve this, but I am not sure how to get the grouping window that I desire.

```py
df_window_index = (
    data.group_by_dynamic(
        index_column="date", every="1m", by="symbol"
    )
    .agg()
    .with_columns(
        pl.int_range(0, pl.len()).over("symbol").alias("window_index")
    )
)
data = data.join_asof(df_window_index, on="date", by="symbol").sort(
    "symbol"
)
```

Using a `timedelta` instead of a string didn't seem to solve the issue.

On the left is the code above, and the image on the right is when I make `every=timedelta(days=31)`. Is still doesnt make sense to me why Polars is pulling those dates for a 31 day timedelta.

[image: Trying TimeDelta]

Any help would be much appreciated, or any tips to point me in the right direction! Thanks!

#### Data:

```py
df = pl.read_csv(b"""
date,open,high,low,close,volume,dividends,stock_splits,symbol,window_index
2021-01-04T00:00:00.000000000,133.52,133.61,126.76,129.41,143301900,0.0,0.0,AAPL,0
2021-01-05T00:00:00.000000000,128.89,131.74,128.43,131.01,97664900,0.0,0.0,AAPL,0
2021-01-06T00:00:00.000000000,127.72,131.05,126.38,126.6,155088000,0.0,0.0,AAPL,0
2021-01-07T00:00:00.000000000,128.36,131.63,127.86,130.92,109578200,0.0,0.0,AAPL,1
2021-01-08T00:00:00.000000000,132.43,132.63,130.23,132.05,105158200,0.0,0.0,AAPL,1
2021-01-11T00:00:00.000000000,129.19,130.17,128.5,128.98,100384500,0.0,0.0,AAPL,1
2021-01-12T00:00:00.000000000,128.5,129.69,126.86,128.8,91951100,0.0,0.0,AAPL,1
2021-01-13T00:00:00.000000000,128.76,131.45,128.49,130.89,88636800,0.0,0.0,AAPL,1
2021-01-14T00:00:00.000000000,130.8,131.0,128.76,128.91,90221800,0.0,0.0,AAPL,1
2021-01-15T00:00:00.000000000,128.78,130.22,127.0,127.14,111598500,0.0,0.0,AAPL,1
2021-01-19T00:00:00.000000000,127.78,128.71,126.94,127.83,90757300,0.0,0.0,AAPL,1
2021-01-20T00:00:00.000000000,128.66,132.49,128.55,132.03,104319500,0.0,0.0,AAPL,1
2021-01-21T00:00:00.000000000,133.8,139.67,133.59,136.87,120150900,0.0,0.0,AAPL,1
2021-01-22T00:00:00.000000000,136.28,139.85,135.02,139.07,114459400,0.0,0.0,AAPL,1
2021-01-25T00:00:00.000000000,143.07,145.09,136.54,142.92,157611700,0.0,0.0,AAPL,1
2021-01-26T00:00:00.000000000,143.6,144.3,141.37,143.16,98390600,0.0,0.0,AAPL,1
2021-01-27T00:00:00.000000000,143.43,144.3,140.41,142.06,140843800,0.0,0.0,AAPL,1
2021-01-28T00:00:00.000000000,139.52,141.99,136.7,137.09,142621100,0.0,0.0,AAPL,1
2021-01-29T00:00:00.000000000,135.83,136.74,130.21,131.96,177523800,0.0,0.0,AAPL,1
2021-02-01T00:00:00.000000000,133.75,135.38,130.93,134.14,106239800,0.0,0.0,AAPL,1
2021-02-02T00:00:00.000000000,135.73,136.31,134.61,134.99,83305400,0.0,0.0,AAPL,1
2021-02-03T00:00:00.000000000,135.76,135.77,133.61,133.94,89880900,0.0,0.0,AAPL,1
2021-02-04T00:00:00.000000000,136.3,137.4,134.59,137.39,84183100,0.0,0.0,AAPL,1
2021-02-05T00:00:00.000000000,137.35,137.42,135.86,136.76,75693800,0.2,0.0,AAPL,1
""".strip(), try_parse_dates=True)
```

Comment: Could you provide code that creates simple DataFrame of example data with the expected result? It'll simplify answering the question.

Comment: You might be happier applying a constant 28- or 30-day rolling window, rather than variable size months.

Comment: @J_H, you might be right. Do you mind suggesting a way to calculate this fixed window calculation while starting from the latest observation and looking backwards?

Comment: Just replace your “1m” with “28d”, or use a datetime.timedelta().

Comment: even if i were to do that, the rolling_window starts at the earliest timestamp, not the latest. They key is to work backwards from todays date

Comment: When i do some testing, `"1m"` is different grouping than `"31d"`? @Hericks @J_H

Comment: `m` is minutes. `mo` is months.

Comment: I have verified and, in the example above, using `period="31d"` gives the same result as `period="1mo"`. Also, the windows are backwards-looking.

Comment: That is odd @hericks, when I run the code above, with the two different strings, I get different groupings for the added `window_index`...see the above picture.


I did find that `period="31d"` == `period=timedelta(days=31)`

Comment: Can you show me an example where `1mo` == `31d`?

Comment: I have shown an example of how `1mo` != `31d`.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the first image saying rows `0-2` should be window 0 and rows `3-24` should be window 1? For me, `1mo` != `31d` because `mo` truncates to the month start. The inlined data here (is from the other question) and does not match what is in the images - which is confusing. You can use `print(data.write_csv())` to give you the correct data and update the sample.

Comment: For general time offsets (3mo, 2w, 15s, etc.), this would require a version of group_by_dynamic that has an end_with parameter (instead of a start_by parameter). For specific time offsets (e.g. just weeks), one might be able to come up with a custom solution. However, the general solution is more sophisticated. One could try to set the offset parameter in a way that produces the desired result. That would still require some general timedelta algebra. Moreover, the offset parameter is fixed, but it needs to be set for each group separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To label non-overlapping *k* month time-windows starting from the latest date in each group and going backwards, you could use the following helper function.

```py
def create_monthly_window_index(col: str, k: int = 1):
    year_diff = pl.col(col).last().dt.year() - pl.col(col).dt.year()
    month_diff = pl.col(col).last().dt.month() - pl.col(col).dt.month()
    day_indicator = pl.col(col).dt.day() > pl.col(col).last().dt.day()
    return (12 * year_diff + month_diff - day_indicator) // k
```

It can be used as follows.

```py
df.with_columns(create_monthly_window_index("date", k=1).alias("window_index").over("group"))
```

Note that the general case of arbitrary time windows is more involved (as outlined in my comment).

Comment: So to create arbitrary windows, starting from the most recent that are not just a `1m` window, would require a helper function per window size?

Comment: @JJFantini The helper function above could be generalised to handle *k* month windows for any positive integer *k*. However, to also handle weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds, etc. You'd need separate helper functions. Weeks and days would actually be easier, because the difference between two dates in days is easily defined and the difference in weeks can be derived using modulo arithmetic.

Comment: How would you suggest generalizing the function for months?

I'm working on one, but stepping through Polars expressions while debugging is not possible, so need to familiarize myself.

Comment: @JJFantini Your proposal looks good. Floor division seems like the way to go.

Comment: How could you do this for days? Wouldn't it be best to use days, because all intervals can be broken down easily into the number of days?

Comment: @JJFantini For days it is indeed simple and floor division can be used again for *k* day windows - same for weeks (do it for days, then floor division by 7 * k).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257067/discussion-between-jj-fantini-and-hericks).